Un saluto carissimo a randomatlabuser
Con questo post voglio salutare randomatlabuser, ora user193, il cui account, come da sua richiesta al team di StackExchange, è stato oggi rimosso dal sito.
Dispiace davvero tanto, lui (o lei), con @DaG e pochi altri, ha dato al sito un grandissimo contributo di qualità in questo primo - e forse ultimo - anno di vita.
Ripeto, sono dispiaciuto e spero che altri si uniscano al mio saluto.
Ciao Random, grazie.

ENGLISH VERSION
With this post I greet randomatlabuser, now user193, who—due to their request—has been removed from the site today.
I'm really sorry, since he (or she), with DaG and few others, gave this site a great contribution during the first—and maybe the last—year of its life.
Again, I'm sorry and I hope that others will join my greetings.
Hello randomatlabuser, thanks.

È possibile saperne qualcosa di più? Si sa perché se ne sia andato? Come si è saputo?

Mi unisco anch'io a questo saluto a randomatlabuser. Anche a me dispiace molto, l'ho già espresso nel chat. Grazie mille, Random!

Forse qualcuno dovrebbe fare la traduzione all'inglese.

@Joiner è riferito al fatto che se il numero di domande resta così basso il sito chiude.

@DaG penso sia andato via per alcune discussioni con l'utente 'bobbie'; discussioni dove non è stato per nulla tutelato dai moderatori. Peraltro c'era anche un suo metapost al riguardo.

Il sito sta crescendo e come tutte le risorse non è immune da attacchi di gente che vuole solo scatenare polemiche e insultare gli altri. Mi scuso in quanto moderatore se la comunità ritiene che non ho agito a dovere sulla faccenda, della quale ho parlato direttamente con randomatlabuster stesso.

@martina: Penso che tu abbia fatto quello che hai ritenuto più corretto in una situazione molto difficile. Anch'io credo che il sito sia in crescita. Non preoccuparvi: per quanto mi riguarda, io vi farò più domande. :-)

Thanks for taking the time to post this. Would you please translate it to English as well? The SE team asks that all meta posts are available in English as well as Italian; I explained the reason for this policy here.

@Charo L'utente 'bobbie', meramente un provocatore, andava sospeso almeno per un mese, per iniziare. Il non aver adottato tale provvedimento per tempo ci ha fatto perdere il migliore dei nostri utenti con grave danno per la qualità del sito nonché ci ha fatto perdere un amico dalla smisurata pazienza.

@AnaHevesi I did my best.

@ElberichSchneider: Anch'io ho chiesto di tradurre il post all'inglese. Dunque, grazie per averlo fatto e grazie anche a DaG per aver corretto la versione in inglese.

Don't let this site die! Italian <3
You guys have some smart idea to get more questions and the site out of beta stage?
